# Hibernate/JPA TransactionManagment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0

First of All I have to apologize for the semi-psuedo code as the classes I am going to reference are all too big and are pointless except for a few lines of each class to ask my question.
To Start off I am using 
Jboss 6.3.2 EAP 
Hibernate
EJB 3.0

I have two different EJB Classes

They are

Service Layer

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class ServiceClass implements ILocalService
{
   @EJB
   ILocalDao localDao;

    @Override
   public myObject find(String id)
   {
      localDao.findByPK(id);
   }

   @TransactionalAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   @Override
   public void create(myObject obj)
   {
      localDao.create(obj);
   }

   @TransactionalAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
   @Override
   public void update(myObject obj)
   {
      localDao.findByPK(obj.getId());
      localDao.update(obj);
   }       
}
```

DAO Layer

```
@Stateless
@TransactionalAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class DaoClass extends AbstractDaoClass<myObject> implements ILocalDao
{
    @Override
    public myObject findByPK(String id)
    {
        super.find(id);
    }
}
```

Okay with those two classes laid out. Trust me that everything else is correctly configured interface Classes, Abstract Class, persistence.xml, etc.

The question is How does the find method in the ServiceClass work?  With the NOT_SUPPORTED being assigned to this method I would think that the DaoClass call would throw a Exception because no Transaction has been started yet and I am making the entire class MANDATORY.  But my running app says otherwise.

1. To verify that no transaction is being created on the DaoClass.find method.  I put in the @TransactionalAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER).  And re-ran the application.  Still works.
2. To verify that the NEVER works I call the ServiceClass's update method.  Throws an exception as expected.

To round this all out I have looked at many online resources(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html, etc) I have looked into the source files for the EJB 3.0 and Jboss...I am not seeing anything.

So questions I have pondered

1. Is the TransctionAttributeType.MANDATORY on the class level not
   working as I expect it to in the DaoClass?
2. TransactionManagement on the ServiceClass creating a Transaction on init of the ServiceClass and then the NOT_SUPPORTED suspending this transaction?

I am in the process of writing up some tests to hopefully log the transaction's behavior and see what is going on.  But hopefully someone here can shed some light sooner and relieve this huge question mark I have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, @TransactionManagement without parameters is useless, since default value is TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER and EJB uses TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER implicitly.